# usage of javascript closure function

Tags: javascript, closures, throttling

I am trying to figure out how to work with a closure function.
On a click event, I want to determine values of `parm1` and `parm2` and display them in a div,
then update new values to an table with an SQL statement.

If user clicks repeatedly, I want to throttle (debounce) and only perform SQL update 5 seconds after user stops clicking. However, display of `parm1` and `parm2` should occur on each click.

I am unsure of how to pass the parms to the SQL process.

```
(function() {
  // create debounced function
  var d_process = $.debounce(SQLprocess, 5000);

  $('#myButton').click(function() {
    // determine parameters
    var parm1 = 1 + 1;                       // edit: added var
    $(".div_1").text(parm1);

    var parm2 = 2+2;                      // edit: added var
    $(".div_2").text(parm2);

    d_process();
  });
}());


function SQLprocess(parm1, parm2) {
  //perform an SQL update
}
```

Reference:
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-debounce/

Comment: the way you declared parm1 and parm2 you can just use them directly in your functions, they are global scope. Also another way to implement the "debounce" is to disable the button for 5 seconds after it's been clicked.

Comment: Chao -true on the first point. For thr second, the button is used to add adjust an alarm clock by 1 minutes, so user should be able to click multiole times.  I just don't want to update datbase until he is finished clicking.

Answer (score 4):

To pass SQLprocess with parameters to the debounce function, change this:

```
var d_process = $.debounce(SQLprocess, 5000);
```

to this:

```
var d_process = $.debounce(function() {SQLprocess(parm1, parm2)}, 5000);
```

This creates an anonymous function with no parameters that is passed to debounce.  But that anonymous function calls SQLprocess with the right parmeters.

---

Some people ask why you can't do this:

```
var d_process = $.debounce(SQLprocess(parm1, parm2), 5000);
```

The answer is because, in the Javavscript language, `SQLprocess(parm1, parm2)` is a function call.  It will execute that function immediately and pass the return value to `$.debounce()` which is not what you want.  `$.debounce` is expecting a function with no arguments so that's what you have to pass it.  The way to get your arguments to `SQLprocess` is to wrap that in a function that has no arguments.  It does not have to be an anonymous function.  It could also be like this with a named function if you want:

```
function myFunctionWrapper() {
    SQLprocess(parm1, parm2);
}

var d_process = $.debounce(myFunctionWrapper, 5000);
```

Comment: simple as this!?  why don't we put brackets on the {SQLprocess()} in the first place?

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge: Because the anonymous function syntax in JS is the verbose `function(){}` stuff. This aint ruby :P

Comment: @MustaphaGeorge - I added to my answer to explain why you can't just add the parameters inline.